# Does ember-cli-cordova support the POD structure?

Tags: cordova, ember.js

I use the POD structure in my ember.js application.
It works well on the browser.

Then I transferred my code into the environment of ember-cli-cordova.
Nothing shows on screen after I installed the app on my phone.

```
[app]
  [application]
    template.hbs
  [index]
    route.js
    template.hbs
```

[application]template.hbs

```
<h1>Template<h1>
{{outlet}}
```

[index]template.hbs

```
<h1>Index<h1>
{{outlet}}
```

.ember-cli

```
"usePods": true
```

What's wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer seems to be ember-cli-cordova does not support the POD structure right now.

Comment: Reference [Ember CLI and Cordova](http://lelandbatey.com/posts/2015/02/ember-and-cordova/), under this structure the POD structure works well.